# Faster partial screenshot workflow

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I take a lot of partial screenshots. I invoke the GNOME screenshot, select "Select area to grab", click "Take Screenshot", drag a region, click "Copy to Clipboard", and paste.

How can I speed up this operation? I would like to invoke the region selection with a single keyboard shortcut, with the selection automatically copied to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Bind a keyboard shortcut to `gnome-screenshot -a -c` to immediately grab an area and copy it to clipboard.